# total_weight column in sales_flat_shipment is always null in enterprise 1.13.0.2

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping, sales, flat

As the title says: `total_weight` column in `sales_flat_shipment` is always null.

Can this be a bug?

Comment: or backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I have just made investigation.

`total_weight` field is created but is not used in the code.

Using search I did not found setting or getting value from array with key `total_weight`.

Also there no `getTotalWeight` and `setTotalWeight` functions usage.

So I can say that this functionality is not used anymore.

The only place where it can be used is to save TotalWeight value from FedEx api responses.